# ASP.NET in Linux !

Tags: asp.net, linux

Hi i know it sounds weird but is it possible to run ASP.NET code in LINUX any how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out mono.

It is an open source cross platform implementation of the CLR.

http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: Good luck finding Mono hosting though.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET) project.